# Relation map between YML and Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to create some kind of relation between YML where I put name of days eg.:

```
0: Sunday
1: Monday
...
6: Saturday
```

On the other hand I would like to create entity called Company with many fields in table eg. `id, name, description` etc.

Is it possible to create relation map between YML and Entities called OpenHoursMap in form like this:
`day_id, company_id, open_hour, close_hour`?

If yes, could you tell me the fastest way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you are trying to do but maybe you could do a custom form type similar to the `CountryType` or `LocaleType` ?

Comment: Hi Christoper, the form is not a problem. The problem concerns relations in database. So, I have YML file with days, the form can be presented in a form: "day: input_open_hour, input_close_hour" and now the question is: how can I create the table OpenHoursMap in symfony2 and connect this table with data from YML?